# Mustache template only sending first word of input to server

Tags: node.js, express, mustache

I'm using a form to capture information from a list and save it to a new table on my database. When the restaurant name is more than one word, i.e. New York, it will ignore everything after the first word adding only the first word to the database. Is there a way to fix this?

View:

```
{{#allRestaurantsData}}

<div class="listing">
  <form action="/restaurants" method="post">
    <h2> {{restaurant.name}}
      <input type="image" src="../wishlisticon.png" />
    </h2>

      <img id="image" src="{{restaurant.featured_image}}" width='500' height='300' alt="picture unavailable">

      <ul>
          <li>Address :{{ restaurant.location.address}}</li>
          <li> {{restaurant.location.locality}}</li>
          <li>{{restaurant.location.city}}</li>
          <li>{{restaurant.location.zip}}</li>
      </ul>

      <div id="comments">
      </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="restaurant_id" value={{restaurant.id}}>
        <input type="hidden" name="restaurant_name" value={{restaurant.name}}>

        <input type="hidden" name="restaurant_city" value={{restaurant.location.city}}>
    </form>
</div>
{{/allRestaurantsData}}
```

Controller:

```
router.post("/restaurants", restaurantsModel.create, (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Hitting /restaurants", res.locals.listitem);
});
```

Model:

```
restaurantsModel.create = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("from restaurants.Model", req.body);
    db
        .manyOrNone(
            "INSERT INTO restaurants (res_id, name, city) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *;",
            [
                req.body.restaurant_id,
                req.body.restaurant_name,
                req.body.restaurant_city
            ]
        )
```

Comment: Hi jenlearnsdev! Could you edit your question to include your backend code so that we can help debug it? Thanks!

Comment: just did. Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing both words in the `console.log` in the model?

Comment: No, I can see it's taking only the first word. I think mustache might not do well with spaces, not sure.

Comment: Could you share the code that's reading the value out of the input? For example, where you're making your ajax request to the backend?

Comment: sure, it's a method on the form.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial an error, I found the answer. I changed added quotation marks to the value inputs in the following two line.

```
<input type="hidden" name="restaurant_name" value="{{restaurant.name}}" >


<input type="hidden" name="restaurant_city" value="{{restaurant.location.city}}">
```